# JDBC query run faster second time

Tags: java, jdbc

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT id FROM accounts LIMIT 1");

    rs.next();
    long id = rs.getLong("id");
    conn.close();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time: " + (end - start));
}
```

And I see

```
time: 17
time: 1
time: 0
time: 0
time: 1
...
```

So, is jdbc somehow cache result? Why first time is so slow and following are so fast?

Comment: It's not JDBC, it's the database that will cache the data.

Comment: It turns out that databases cache queries.

Comment: The one thing JDBC cache (well, I check on one jar) is a map to find the index of a column based on his name (`getXXX(String)`), this is store in the resultset, to be faster to read the next rows (but will be forgotten for the next query)

Comment: @AxelH That is only in the same result set, not (likely) over multiple executions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That what I said **(but will be forgotten for the next query)**

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible reasons for this behaviour, and it is not untypical:

1. As khelwood said in the comments: Databases are optimized to cache table contents in their memory once they were accessed. So with the second call, the database may find the data in memory and has not to load it from disk.
2. Some implementations of `DataSource` cache the connections, so the second call to `createConnection()` does not need to create a new connection (which is costly), it will just reuse the old one.
3. With the first call to `getConnection()` and `createStatement()` many classes used by the JDBC driver may get loaded at that time, which is not necessary in the second loop.
4. If such a loop runs very often, also the Hotspot Compiler may have JIT'ed your Java code, so that it runs faster after some loops.

Probably reasons 1 and 2 have the biggest impact on the observed behavior, reason 4 will probably not arise with only 200 loops.

Comment: 5. Sometimes first use of branch of code requires classloading (for classes already not loaded). This is general rule in java, not only database solutions